# Add An Array to An Object

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I'm trying to add an array:

`String[] pets = {"dog", "cat"}`

to an object:

`Object[][] petList = { };`

The final result of the `Object` should be:

`Object[][] petList = { {"dog", "cat"} };`

I tried simply using `petList.add(pets);` but had no luck.

I am trying to use this `Object` to input values into a `JTable`. I'm not sure if one can use `ArrayList`, but I'm not even sure how to use it.

Comment: Does object NEED to be a 2d array for your solution?

Comment: Yes. The `JTable` I have has 2 columns, so the array must have 2 values.

Comment: Ah I understand, I misread the first time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would give the location in `petList` where you want `pets` stored, like such:

```
petList[i][j] = pets;
```

EDIT: After reading your comments, I think you want to do something more like this:

```
petList[i][0] = pets[0];
petList[i][1] = pets[1];
```

Where `i` is whatever row you want to place the data into. This will put the two animals next two each other in your 2-dimensional grid.

Also to note, based on your needs, you may just want to use a `String[][]` instead of an `Object[][]`.

Comment: So if I looped this and kept changing `pets`, would it just keep adding pets onto the next open slot?...

`petList[i][0] = pets;`

`i++;`

Comment: Glad to have helped!  best of luck with the rest of your project :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
String[] pets = {"dog", "cat"};
Object[][] petList = {pets}; // Only pets is added, and you can't add any more
System.out.println(petList[0][0]); // dog
System.out.println(petList[0][1]); // cat
```

But the problem here would be that once `petList` is created, its size is fixed and determined by the no. of elements provided when initializing. And that may be something you'd like to avoid.

Instead you could create a 2d array and assign its elements with the arrays you want. Like this

```
String[] pets = {"dog", "cat"};
Object[][] petList = new Object[10][2]; // Example
petList[0] =  pets; // assigning the arrays to elements
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String[] pets = {"dog", "cat"};

    Object[][] petList = new Object[2][2];
    petList[0][0] =  pets[0];
    petList[0][1] =  pets[1];
```